# Powershell- compare files and take action

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to create a powershell script to compare two IP addresses out of two different text files then take an action base on if they match or they don't match. See below

```
(Invoke-WebRequest ifconfig.me/ip).content | Out-File "C:\test\test2.txt"
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$File = "C:\test\test.txt"
$File2 = "C:\test\test2.txt"

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content $File2) -DifferenceObject (Get-
Content $File) -IncludeEqual
```

If the two files match I obviously get a ==, or an => if they don't match. I'm not sure how to use == or => as a variable to continue the rest of the script. Any help or recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to check the value of the `SideIndicator` property; e.g.:

```
if ( (Compare-Object (Get-Content test1.txt) (Get-Content test2.txt) -IncludeEqual).SideIndicator -eq '==' ) {
  "The files are equal"
}
```

`Compare-Object` outputs nothing if there are no differences and you omit `-IncludeEqual`, so the above can also be written as:

```
if ( -not (Compare-Object (Get-Content test1.txt) (Get-Content test2.txt)) ) {
  "The files are equal"
}
```

Comment: How do I add a .SideIndicator for <= ?

Comment: What's provoking the question?

Comment: Still a major noob at powershell but the way I see it, I'll need to add the second variable to take a separate action if the IP addresses don't match.

Comment: You can use an `else` clause. Run the command `help about_If` for information on how to use the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a variable to the `Compare-Object` result. When I did a quick test it seems like nothing is returned if the two objects matched. So you would have to check for $null in the value of the variable.

```
$a = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject "abc" -DifferenceObject "abc"
if($a -ne $null){continue working here}else{do other action here}
```

For more info check out:
https://ss64.com/ps/compare-object.html